# rename all method,function,etc (obfuscate only source code not exe file)

Tags: c#, winforms, obfuscation

I need to create a macro to go through my 100000 line project and rename each function to random strings.

Has anyone done something like this?

I know i  can use from Dotfuscator or many other programs but I want to see,edit,select,etc my source code means I don't want obfuscate exe file

I want obfuscate only source code for example only form1 (Form1.cs , Form1.Designer.cs , Form1.resx ...)

have any solution ?

Comment: Why would you do that ? This is no criticism, but I'm just being curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My result :**

No any app for this work but we can do it

- Build
- project Obfuscate project with minimal option (I'm using from `Crypto    Obfuscator For .Net 2015` )
- Decode final file (Obfuscated file) (I'm    using from `.NET Reflector 8.3` )
- Export code and save it.
- Open new source solution with VS
- Now use from `macro` or `replace with regex` to remove `Dispose` and `InitializeComponent` `method` and also private or public `Label, button , Checkbox , Panel , ListBox , etc` in this solution
- Now open last solution and use from macro or manually replace all text in `public partial class` from new solution (coded) to last solution (source) and build your solution again
- Check error list and solve error (for me is about 3-4 for `using` or `label,list,etc` which created from the source and not exist in design.cs)
- repeat this work for all `class , form , etc`
- Finished !

this is work for me and fast but not to mach .... I don't find any better work !